# Rest In Pieces, where is the Pi Graveyard?

Tags: discussion

Doh! Shortcuicuited my Pi today while trying to finalise the "Underhouse rover V1" for a friend who needs his under floor inspecting at his new house (We think something died there) Oh well, one for the gravey yard, as R&D goes - but good excuse to get some B+ models in.

[image]

Comment: Unlucky :) But this is not about Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, and so is OT!

Comment: This Pi has been denied eternal memoery *sob*  :)

Comment: @ppumkin just buy another one, it is cheap.

Comment: Waiting for Cyber Monday . ehhehe :)